# Pushing TabBar Controller on Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am building an app in which at some point I have to show TabBar Controller but my app allready has Navigation Controller, so the most obvious sollution would be to push TabBar onto Navigation.
Apple in it's developer documentation states following:

> > "You never want to push a tab bar controller onto the navigation stack of a 
> >     navigation controller. Doing so creates an unusual situation whereby the tab bar appears only while a specific view controller 
> >     is at the top of the navigation stack. 
> >     Tab bars are designed to be persistent, and so this transient approach can be confusing to users."

Well I made it this way not knowing about this recomendation :). Now I am wondering if my app could me rejected because of this. Do you have any experiences with this? What do you think aboute this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they're going to reject your app (not sure about it, but I don't think anyone can be), but your structure seems very confusing.

have a look at this: [iOs Human Interface Guideline](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html)

For example:

"Use a tab bar to give users access to different perspectives on the same set of data or different subtasks related to the overall function of your app. When you use a tab bar, follow these guidelines:

Don’t use a tab bar to give users controls that act on elements in the current mode or screen. If you need to provide controls for your users, use a toolbar instead (for usage guidelines, see “Toolbar”).

In general, use a tab bar to organize information at the application level. A tab bar is well-suited for use in the main app view because it’s a good way to flatten your information hierarchy and provide access to several peer information categories or modes at one time."

I think you should transform your tab bar in a tool bar.

Comment: Thanks For the answer I'll surely think about this suggestion.